what is IID (issue ID) in compustat database
I have recently download daily stock price data from Compustat for selected Ticker symbols. The downloaded data has stock prices for multiple Issue ID. I don't know which stock prices to take for any analysis purpose (which IID issue price is appropriate for any stock return related analysis)?. For more info on IID see this http://zeerovery.nl/blogfiles/Comp-IID.pdf
I tried looking any solution on the internet but didn't find any.
